# Pyspark: SVM_model.predict() -> "dimension mismatch"

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, svm, apache-spark-mllib

I am attempting to test various candidate models on collection of ~20k LabeledPoints with ~5000 features for the purpose of binary classification.

I created a feature vector using VectorAssembler on my input space containing numeric features, sparse vectors, etc. and then converted those vectors (along with the label) into LabeledPoints.

```
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols = ["fileSize", "hour", "day", "month", "title_tfidf", "ct_tfidf", "excerpt_tfidf", "regex_tfidf"], outputCol="features")
training_set_vector = assembler.transform(training_set).select("Target", "features")
training_set_labeled = training_set_vector.rdd.map(lambda x: Row(label=x[0],features=DenseVector(x[1].toArray()))).map(lambda row: LabeledPoint(row[1], [row[0]]))
```

The output of training_set_vector and training_set_labeled are as follows:

> [Row(Target=0, features=SparseVector(2273, {0: 8397.0, 1: 13.0, 2:
>   12.0, 3: 1.0, 8: 3.3147, 82: 5.721, 370: 0.2546, 410: 7.0356, 418: 5.3786, 429: 12.4219, 623: 7.3906, 1061: 9.3078, 1637: 2.3682, 1647: 2.716}))] [LabeledPoint(0.0, [8397.0,13.0,12.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,3.31468140319,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, .... ,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0])]

Then I took the LabeledPoints and fit RandomForest, SVM, and GBT models.

```
RF_model = RandomForest.trainClassifier(training_set_labeled, numClasses=2, categoricalFeaturesInfo = {}, numTrees=10, featureSubsetStrategy = "auto", impurity='gini', maxDepth=4, maxBins=32)
SVM_model = SVMWithSGD.train(training_set_labeled, iterations=500)
GBT_model = GradientBoostedTrees.trainClassifier(training_set_labeled, categoricalFeaturesInfo = {}, maxDepth=4, maxBins=32, numIterations=5)
```

Everything ran smoothly up to this point, the problem came when I attempted to apply these models to the test set (same dimensionality as the training set). Here is the code I used to apply to the test set:

```
predictions_RF = RF_model.predict(test_set_labeled.map(lambda r: r.features))
predictions_SVM = SVM_model.predict(test_set_labeled.map(lambda r: r.features))
predictions_GBT = GBT_model.predict(test_set_labeled.map(lambda r: r.features))
```

The RF and GBT models completed successfully:

```
print predictions_RF.take(5)
print predictions_GBT.take(5)
```

> [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] 
>   [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]

But when applying the SVM model, I'm getting the following error:

> AssertionError: dimension mismatch

Running "print SVM_model" reveals that there are only ~500 weights but there are ~5k features. I'm assuming this is the issue but I'm not entirely sure how handle this. Anybody have similar issues and able to point me in the direction of how I can apply this SVM model (or some other SVM model) to the test set?